# iPhone animated view overlay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xib

I have a few XIBs that are my pages, and i'm using presentmodalviewcontroller to switch between them with some buttons. Now I want to use other buttons to pull up overlays on  those views. How I have it now is I have a button which simply toggles the "Hidden" property on the UIImageview.

What are options for animating the show/hide functionality of this? I'd like some sort of zoom-in or zoom-out effect when the overlay is called up rather than just suddenly showing/hiding.

```
-(IBAction)basketballbutton{
if (basketball.hidden == YES)
    basketball.hidden = NO;
else if (basketball.hidden == NO)
    basketball.hidden = YES;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate the view opacity using the alpha property.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[basketball setAlpha:([basketball alpha] > 0.0) ? 0.0f : 1.0f];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will animate the showing and hiding of the view.

Here is how you set the transform for scaling:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
// Scale up 2x
[basketball setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much better. How about scale? Is there a similar method to animate the scale of the image?

Comment: Yes. Look at setting the transform on the view--specifically you need to set the scale transform using CGAffineTransformMakeScale (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeScale)

Comment: I updated my answer with some code to show the scale transform.